# @Formula not working in hibernate with object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a enum of few status value

**NEW, REVIEWD, PUBLISHED, PENDING, UPDATED, SPAM, DUPLICATE, IRRELEVANT, UNPUBLISHED**

I don't want to use them as enumerated so created one entity for that. For convenient I want to keep a column in entity to initialize status from enum and convert that enumerated value to a Object of status entity. for this..

I have two entity. I want to refer a column with value from another entity.

Basically I want to initialize a object with formula.

**Entities are**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_status")
public class EventStatus {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="eventStatusId")
    private Integer eventStatusId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(unique = true,name="eventStatusType")
    private EventStatusType eventStatusType;

    public EventStatus() {
        this(EventStatusType.NEW);
    }

    public EventStatus(EventStatusType eventStatusType) {
        super();
        this.eventStatusType = eventStatusType;
    }

    public Integer getEventStatusId() {
        return eventStatusId;
    }

    public EventStatusType getEventStatusType() {
        return eventStatusType;
    }

    public void setEventStatusId(Integer eventStatusId) {
        this.eventStatusId = eventStatusId;
    }

    public void setEventStatusType(EventStatusType eventStatusType) {
        this.eventStatusType = eventStatusType;
    }
}
```

I have another entity in which I am referring object of this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Event implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    public EventStatusType eventStatusType = EventStatusType.NEW;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = EventStatus.class)
    @Formula("select * from event_status where eventStatusId= 1")
    private EventStatus status;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public EventStatus getStatus() {
        System.out.println("Event.getStatus() " + status);
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(EventStatus status) {
        System.out.println("Event.setStatus()");
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

This is not giving any exception but not initializing this value.
Is it possible to initialize this EntityStatus with value of eventStatusType in Event entity

Comment: `@Formula` must return what would usually return `column` mapping. So in this case, Hibernate would need to get **status-ID**. That should be result of the `@Formula`, not selection of that object...

Comment: You mean I have to change my sql to 'select eventStatusId from event_status where eventStatusId= 1'

Comment: Well, no! that won't help, because: what we need is to create some smart selection... in fact, we should say @Formula("(1)"). Believe or not, that is enough for Hibernate. Why? Hibernate will take that value and search for `EventStatus` with provided id... make sense?. Your approach would be working but is not what we need. We are trying to replace the column with some smarter value, evaluated on DB side...

Comment: Not working giving exception 'java.sql.SQLException: Field 'status' doesn't have a default value'

Comment: @Formula is not nothing complicated. It really does help us to solve situation, when there is no column with proper value. We can compute it. But the issue is: it could be readonly...

Comment: @RadimKöhler Hey I understood that @ Formula is read only but your proposed solution is giving exception @ Formula(1). Take a look at separate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467745/formula-to-fetch-an-entity-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to explain that based on the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/):

#### [5.1.4.1.5. Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3147)

> Sometimes, you want the Database to do some computation for you rather than in the JVM, you might also create some kind of virtual column. You can use a SQL fragment (aka formula) instead of mapping a property into a column. This kind of property is read only (its value is calculated by your formula fragment).

```
@Formula("obj_length * obj_height * obj_width")
public long getObjectVolume()
```

> The SQL fragment can be as complex as you want and even include subselects.

...

#### [5.1.7.1. Using a foreign key or an association table](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

...

> Note
>
> You can use a SQL fragment to simulate a physical join column using the `@JoinColumnOrFormula` / `@JoinColumnOrformulas` annotations (just like you can use a SQL fragment to simulate a property column via the `@Formula` annotation).

```
@Entity
public class Ticket implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula="(firstname + ' ' + lastname)")
    public Person getOwner() {
        return person;
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, we should use **`insertable = false, updatable = false`**, because such mapping is not editable

Comment: Is these formula columns are read-only. If is that so then it can not help in my scenario. I want to change a enumeration value to Object when I an making and persist

Comment: Look, think about in from SQL point of view. If the column is computed... it could be used to get values. But there is no way how to insert that unpredictable set of source values... so formula == readonly. Sorry, wanted to help ... Enjoy Hibernate anyhow ;) Amazing tool

Comment: Thanks. If you can help. can you tell me best way to manage my Status enum. Actually I want to avoid string values in DB (Repeated). If I keep them in DB then every time I have to set them by fetching from DB. What is the best approach to use.

Comment: Not fully sure if I do understand, because Why there could not be column statusId? and standard many-to-one mapping? That would be way I would go... Also EventStatus should be in DB as a table. Why? foreign key constraints. That's my experience. And I have to say: like it. The run-time is ok (workin with enum) and DB is as well, because it is readoble even without code! (foreign keys, event status table). That would be my way.

Comment: That's Ok. But in-case suppose in future I made change in enum all the old values in table will fail.

Comment: That's the trick. If the enum will have id - integer. This will be persited in table [EventStatus] with those ids. Without proper update to DB, you won't be able to change your enum. And that is a **big helper**. Why? because otherwise in the system would be stale/non-existing references... the removed enum values. Does it help?

Comment: So finally conclusion is this. I can not solve this problem with formula. I have to manually maintain this thing.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. @Formula is really not bad feature, sure you will use it later;) but reference handling from WRITE perspective is not applicable here. Good luck with Hibernate ;)

Comment: Thanks. But it will be good if hibernate provide this feature also.