# Alternative for @Formula?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have two objects:

```
@Table(name = "user")
User
@Id
Integer id
Integer uuid;
```

and reservation:

```
@Table(name = "reservation")
Reservation
@Id
Integer id;
Integer uuid;
```

My goal is:

```
@Table(name = "reservation")
Reservation
@Id
Integer id;
Integer uuid;

@Formula("(SELECT * FROM user b  WHERE b.uuid = uuid )")
List<User> users;
```

The problem is `@Formula` doesnt work with objects.

How to include list of all users in reservation with same uuid?

I found this but maybe there is better option
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37502703/3871754

Answer (score 0):

Support of relationships that references non-PK columns is an optional feature. In simple cases it's supported by Hibernate

```
@NotAudited
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
private List<Barrier> barriers = new ArrayList<>();
```

and implemented `Serializable` for `Reservation`